# RelativeLayout.LayoutParams pragmatically adding layouts

Tags: java, android, layout

I looked trough simalar questions and found no answer. After 4 h of searching I finally decided to ask a question.

```
    RelativeLayout layoutOne = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_cell,viewGroup,false);

    RelativeLayout layoutTwo = (RelativeLayout) layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.offer_cell,viewGroup,false);


    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams  param = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    param.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, layoutOne.getId());


    addView(layoutOne);
    addView(layoutTwo,param);
```

IT IS NOT WORKING!!! Going crazzy on this one... Please help.

p.s. 
I already checked the id of layoutOne. It is set.

p.s. 2 
I already tried layoutTwo.setLayoutParams(param);

Comment: I'm guessing this is Java code for android, right? You should add these as tags for a better targeted audience ...

Comment: Are you adding those views to a `RelativeLayout`? What type is `viewgroup`?

Comment: What's going wrong?  (i.e., please be more specific than "it's not working!!!" and we'll have more info to help you diagnose the problem)

Comment: I was adding RelativeLayouts to a class that extends the RelativeLayout. I solved the issue by extending the LinearLayout inside the class instead of RelativeLayout. The strange thing is that it was working OK when I try to align it with parent instead of layoutOne.